# npm list is never empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, terminal, npm

I have created a folder for a new project and I'm about to install a package via `npm`, but before that I run `npm list` and it has a lot stuff there.

Shouldn't it be empty? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you have installed some packages globally.

Comment: @PardeepDhingra `npm list` does not list global packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have `node_modules` somewhere in the parent directories. When npm is looking for `node_modules` in current directory with no success, it will look in parent directory and so on.

Comment: Isn't it a part of `npm list` output? You can share part of output in your question.

Comment: I've found it, but I've never installed any of these modules, does it ship with the installation of the `npm`? Is there any issue on deleting this folder or in order to delete these modules, should I do them manually?